# Login page for php

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to make a login page using php. My registration page is working already but there are errors in the login.
This is my first file.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<body>

<body background="sky.jpg"></body>
<div style="text-align: center;">
<div style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; width: auto; max-width:                
480px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 2px solid #D4D4D4; border-radius: 5px; box-
shadow: 0px 0px 8px #D4D4D4; margin: 50px auto auto;">
<div style="background: #D4D4D4; border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px; padding: 15px;"> 
<span style="font-family: verdana,arial; color: #D4D4D4; font-size: 1.00em; font-
weight:bold;">HEY REGISTER NOW!</span></div>
<div style="background: ; padding: 15px">
<style type="text/css" scoped>
td { text-align:left; font-family: verdana,arial; color: #000000; font-size: 
1.00em; }
input { border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; border-radius: 5px; color: #666666; display: 
inline-block; font-size: 1.00em;  padding: 5px; width: 100%; }
input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] { height: auto; 
width: auto; cursor: pointer; box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #D4D4D4; float: right; margin-
 top: 10px; }
table.center { margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; }
.error { font-family: verdana,arial; color: #000000; font-size: 1.00em; }
</style>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
<input type="hidden" name="hide" value="">
<table class='center'>
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="username"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="password"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Enter"></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>Don't have an admin account yet? Click <a     
href="Register.php">here</a>!</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>Thank you for using Sentence Scramble and Sequencer</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</div></div></div>
```

Followed by my checklogin

```
<?php

// Connect to server and select databse.
$server = 'localhost'; 
$username = 'root'; 
$password = ''; 
$database = 'project'; 
mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM 'register' WHERE username='$myusername' and    
password='$mypassword'";
echo $sql;
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result); 

if($count==1){

session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

And lastly, a file for login_success

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:index.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

'myusername' and 'mypassword' are variables that come from the table 'register' from my database

Comment: please delete your password... delete your question and post it again...

Comment: Change the input name as myusername and mypassword in the login page

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your form so that the username and password input fields match what your form handler script is attempting to validate. Your input fields should look like this:

```
<tr><td>Username:</td><td><input type="text" name="myusername"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type="password" name="mypassword"></td></tr>
```

Comment: Okay the error message for that part is resolved, but there's still another error which is
SELECT * FROM 'register' WHERE username='test' and password='test'
Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\checklogin.php on line 20

Comment: @user3583643 your mysql connection resource isn't defined and you're trying to reference it in the mysql_query function as $con. mysql_query will automatically use the most recent connection without having to explicitly specify it. so you should just chance $result=mysql_query($sql,$con); to $result=mysql_query($sql);

Comment: Did that, now there's an error with the following line

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: @user3583643 its not very helpful if you don't tell me what the error is.

Comment: I'm sorry, the error is Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\checklogin.php on line 20

Comment: @user3583643 you don't want to wrap the table name in quotes within your query. it should be: $sql="SELECT * FROM register WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";

Comment: Alright i've changed it, but the same error occurs.

Comment: @user3583643 change your mysql_query function so we can see where its failing. $result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: SELECT * FROM register WHERE username='New user' and password='555555'Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 0):

Your connection variable not set. Please set it firt. Havent initiated session_start(). Usage of session_register() is deprecated.

```
<?php
session_start()
// Connect to server and select databse.
$server = 'localhost'; 
$username = 'root'; 
$password = ''; 
$database = 'project'; 
$con = mysql_connect($server,$username,$password) or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

$sql="SELECT * FROM 'register' WHERE username='$myusername' and    
password='$mypassword'";
echo $sql;
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result); 

if($count==1){

  $_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;
   $_SESSION['mypassword'] = $mypassword;

   header("location:login_success.php");
   exit;
}
else {
   echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

And lastly, a file for login_success

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])) {
   header("location:index.php");
   exit; 
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Login Successful
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please have a try. Also usage of mysql_* functions going to deprecate. Try to use mysqli_* functions. Have a look here http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php